# Displaying Date and time in textbox

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim formatdate As Date

    If cboPurpose.Text = "Photocopy" Then
        formatdate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 30, Now)
        txtdue.Text = Format(formatdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    ElseIf cboPurpose.Text = "Overnight" Then
        formatdate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 24, Now)
        txtdue.Text = Format(formatdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    End If
```

can someone help me with this? what happen is after i click the save button then that is the time when the time and date will show up. what i want is after i select a condition in my combo box it will automatically display the date and time in my textbox not after i click the save button. . thanks admin/s.

Comment: If you don't want to do something when a `Button` is clicked then don't handle the `Click` event of a `Button`. What event is raised when an item is selected in a `ComboBox`? That's what you should be looking for. Have already looked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the event, the event handler should be comboBox's event OnChange or something.

Try changing the event to combobox and then sending the value to the text box. 
Why not use DateTimePicker control?? Its easy, useful calendar gadget.

Comment: yup! you're right sir.. i put the code in the combo box event . thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are coming from the VB6 world.  There are functions built into the VB.Net Date class that will make adding seconds / minutes / hours / days to a date and also formatting date/time strings much easier. So along with Mario's answer in attaching to the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combo box, I would also say if you are bent on using a text box to display the date, use something like:

```
Select Case cboPurpose.Text
Case "Photocopy"
    txtDue.Text = Now().AddMinutes(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
Case "Overnight"
    txtDue.Text = Now().AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly call the Date time.

```
If cboPurpose.Text = "Photocopy" Then
        txtdue.Text = Datetime.Now.Addminutes(30).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

ElseIf cboPurpose.Text = "Overnight" Then
             txtdue.Text = Datetime.Now.AddDays(1).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
End If
```